# Nodes and Bonds

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

### 1. Which letter replaces the question mark?

[image: Diagram 1]

### 2. Where can #10 be placed in this diagram?

[image: Diagram 2]

### 3. Not a double bond from one node to another here. But where is L?

[image: Diagram 3]

Comment: Do we need to replace the first "?" with a letter or number?

Comment: Is 'letter' correct for 1?

Comment: Letter is correct

Comment: You can also replace it with a number, but that would be a bit more obvious.

Comment: The number missing from 1 is 6. The title implies the letter might be C, but I don't feel good about it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Which letter replaces the question mark?

   > Each bond gives the number of letters in common and in the same position for chemical elements given by their atomic number. 
   >  For example 1~2 = **H**ydrogen ~ **H**elium have 1 bond in common 
   >  
   >  while 1 ~ 7  = Hyd**rogen** ~ Nit**rogen** have 5 - Thanks to **David Starkey**
   >  So number 6 is correct. It has the correct number of bonds since it has one letter in common position with each of the linked atomic numbered elements 
   >  Carbon (6) 
   >  Hydr**o**gen (1) 
   >  Oxyge**n** (8) 
   > Bo**r**on (5) 
   >  Be**r**yllium (4) 
   >  Nitr**o**gen (7) 
   >  So thanks to Ian McDonald the number 6 can be represented by **letter C** for Carbon
2. Where can #10 be placed in this diagram?

   > This time each bond gives the number of letters in common and in the same position for  numbers spelled as words.  
   > For example the bonds with number seven are
   >  Seven
   >  Nin**e**
   >  Thr**e**e
   >  Fi**ve**
   >  **S**ix
   >
   >  So the diagram with 10 would be  [image]
3. Not a double bond from one node to another here. But where is L?

   > Each link gives the letters in common position with letters given by the  [phonetic alphabet](https://www.fourmilab.ch/documents/phoneticalphabet/) - with version A for Alpha and J for Juliett which may vary. 
   >  So L is for Lima and the only letter it has a common one with is K**i**lo so **L** has one bond to **K** 
   >  
   >  This answer was found by user who gave it in an earlier comment - thank you! - I have missed your user name at moment.

Comment: Hyd**rogen** ~ Nit**rogen**  should be 5, right?

Comment: Thanks @DavidStarkey - you are absolutely right. I will edit - and it is 5 bonds.

Comment: Technically, the NATO phonetic alphabet spells the first one "ALFA", which would also share the A of LIMA.